# Удалить элемент из массива по условию

Tags: php

Друзья, подскажите, есть массив с 5-ю элементами, нужно из этого массива удалить все не угодные элементы (в данном случае 3й и 4й элемент):

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "0,91,90,76.5,106,70"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "1,91,89,75,105,70.8"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "2,90,89,74,103,68.8"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "3,-,-,-,-,-"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "4,-,-,-,-,-"
}
```

Все элементы в которых стоят прочерки - нужно удалить. Пробовал делать проверку с счетчиком и проверять по третьему [2] символу в каждой строке, но ловлю себя на мысли, что в архитектуре торможу и существет более элегентный способ получить ожидаемый результат!

```
    $count = 0;
    foreach($arr as $row) {

        if($row[2] == '-') {
            unset($row[$count]);
        } else {
            $count++;
        }

    }
```

UPD Решение найдено, оно подходит в конкретно моем случае! Достаочно проверить по количеству симвалов с строке! Так как у неугодныхэлементов в строке 11 символов, в отличие от всех остальных!

```
    $count = 0;
    foreach($arr as $row) {

        if(strlen($row) === 11) {
            unset($arr[$count]);
        }
        $count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо просто удалить элементы, и вы знаете индексы этих элементов, то можно использовать метод [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php)

```
$index1 = 3;
unset($your_arr[$index1]);
$index2 = 4;
unset($your_arr[$index2]);
```

ну или тоже самое в цикле. Можно сначала найти все значения индексов в которых встречается хотя бы один "-", и потом удалить эти элементы. Ваш метод очень хардкорный, и если в массиве будет что-то неожиданное может не сработать... но если вас устраивает.